# How to find risk contingency reserve?

Tags: probability, math-software, risk-assessment

Attach, is one of the MCQ from exam-engine, I want to know how the answer was calculated. The subject is related to `risk assessment and controls selection.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the expected value of Impact $(I)$ to get the surplus capital.

$E[I] = \sum_{i}p_iI_i = p_AI_A + p_BI_B + \ldots, p_EI_E$

Comment: Your equation is correct, but it does not result in the expected answer.

Comment: It does. Note that for risk $D$, the impact is positive and for others it is negative. $E[I] = -23750$.

Comment: I missed that.  I expect that risks always have negative impact. -1 to the question writer, not to OP.